# How to create a HTML table with dynamic column inside a div

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, html-table

I have a div inside which I want to create an HTML table with a dynamic column.

The nature of the table should be such that one column should be always fixed; then if I want 7 dates to display, it should show 7 dynamic columns; if I selected 15 days to display it should show 15 dynamic columns; and the name of the columns should be as per dates.

The dynamic columns generated should be empty and there is not data to fetch out from anywhere.

Here is the div in my HTML...

```
<div id="main" style="float: left; width:83%; margin-left:5px; margin-top:0px;">
<div id="doclist">
        </div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="tabs">
        <!-- Tabs go here -->
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
        <!-- Tab content goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my HTML table...

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Header Column</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
        <th>Column 4</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><th>Header</th><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td><td>Cell 4</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Header</th><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td><td>Cell 4</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Header</th><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td><td>Cell 4</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Header</th><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td><td>Cell 4</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How can I create this?

Comment: How is your information stored? MySQL? Plain textfiles?

Comment: @Richa I have updated my post with my table HTML..

Comment: how are you fetching the data for this table?

Comment: @user3622611 You haven't mentioned with a single word how you receive your data to the view and what language you're about to use to make this dynamic. What you have in there, css and html, are static in nature and it's impossible to do anything dynamic with them.

Comment: @mrdeveloper At present i want the columns to be empty and later i want to add click event in the column.

Comment: @JaniHyytiäinen  Data columns of the table i want to be empty ..Simply i want dyanamically to get created as per the days of the month..

Comment: @user3622611 so programmatically created data on the ui, with Javascript maybe? And is it OK to use jQuery to manipulate the table based on the data?

Comment: @JaniHyytiäinen Yes its OK to use jquery,ajax.For the table needed suppose i have a button named week and i have clicked on the button then its should show 7 column with the coming 6 days as column name in the table

Comment: @user3622611 Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hsakapandit/jhb86/

Comment: @mrdeveloper Its correct sir ..You can give this as answer and i will markk..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table").hide();
    $("#hide").hide();   
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        $("table").show();
        $("#submit").hide();
$("#hide").show();        



    });
       $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("table").hide();
        $("#submit").show();
$("#hide").hide();        



    });
});
```

Use above JQuery code to show or hide your table.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hsakapandit/jhb86/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "database");
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10");
echo "<table cellspacing='0'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Lastname</th></tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td><td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td></tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

This should work, if you're using a MySQL database to store the information?
Let me know if there's an error, haven't tried the code, just wrote it up. Also if you have any questions about it lmk.

To sort the days etc, just change the ORDER BY part and how many days you would like to show. You would obviously need a column for the days and edit my code a bit.

EDIT; You changed it to AJAX/jQuery, thought you only wanted to grab information from a database and put it inside your table.

Comment: @user3622611 - Didn't know you wanted to use AJAX/jQuery. You didn't state so from the beginning tho.

Comment: I want to use AJAX/Jquery ..And the dynamic column generated should be empty .There is not database operation performed in this

Comment: @user3622611 - So basically you only want to add a colum, with the date for each time you click a button? And each time it would show the day after the last one?

Comment: Yes suppose i have a button named week and i have clicked on the button then its should show 7 column with the coming 6 days as column  name

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you want to have some data. Table is actually an array of objects. Each row representing an object.

```
var row1 = { col1: 'hello', col2: 'world' };
var row2 = { col1: 'hi', col2: 'globe' };
```

Your issue is, when you're dealing with a varying number of properties in such an object and you're looking for a way to loop through object properties. This can be done with for ... in -statement.

```
for (var col in row) {
    // code to add a cell
}
```

To genererate the table you'll need to have your objects in an array.

```
var rows = [ row1, row2 ];
```

You need to have the table tag:

```
$('#content). append('<table>');
```

To build your header row, you need to grab the first item of your array and loop through it's properties.

```
$('#content table').append('tr');
var first = rows[0];
for (var col in first) {
    $('#content table tr').append('<td>' + col + '</td>');
}
```

Then you can move on to building your rows with a for-loop.

```
$('#content table').append('tr');
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    for (var col in first) {
        $('#content table tr').last().append('<td>' + rows[i][col] + '</td>');
    }
}
```

After which you can freely modify your array and your table will adjust yourself according to the data.